# how to get a dynamic html alert content(text) from another div tag by id or class_name?

Tags: javascript, html, alert

using alert of a button tag **onclick** action.
How to get the alert message content/text from another element by id or classname?

**Edited:**

I meant the button tag like the following code..

```html
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
```

I need to replace the string(Hello World) by the innerHTML of another element that is hidden.

Comment: Please explain the question properly.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? And, maybe add some of your attempts?

Comment: If your div has class use document.querySelector('.yourdivclass').innerText or if ids, document.getElementById('#yourId').innerText

Comment: I've edited the question in order anyone needed the same-thing in the future

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly and that will help you further.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The onclick Event</h1>

<p>The onclick event is used to trigger a function when an element is clicked on.</p>

<p id="test">Click Test.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
  alert(test.innerHTML);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, have now unfortunately found no possibility without script. If there is a possibility, I'm happy to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one less code/script and best option yet..!

```html
<button type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML)">click</button>
<div id='test' style='display:none'>hiiiiii</div>
```